# i am face functionality issues even I've updated to the latest version of the OpenAI API but still same error. Can anyone offer insights or solutions

Tags: nlp, openai-api

I'm attempting to utilize the OpenAI API to generate customer service emails tailored to individual customer reviews. Despite updating to the latest version of the OpenAI package, I'm encountering issues with its functionality. Can anyone provide insights or solutions to troubleshoot this problem?
I've included the relevant code snippet and outlined the error I encountered.[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sSAx.png)
error I encountered
"
APIRemovedInV1:

You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: [https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742"](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742%22)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R6TS.png)
I aim to generate customer service email responses using customer emails as prompts and obtain appropriate replies from the OpenAI model

Comment: I would recommend you read the [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742) as the solution is there on the first page.